# Windows 7 path not being set

Tags: windows-7, command-line, python, path

I've read an followed all stack overflow, super user, etc. instructions multiple times, and my GUI window shows the path to be what I want, i.e., python27. However the cmd prompt shows several lines of garbage (I won't retype here , trust me it is 16 lines of garbage with
many lines of repeated paths). I have no idea how it got changed, since   i tried to install active python over my previous python. it is very irritating because I've followed the instructions to the letter and I am familiar with programming, but somehow when i check the path at the cmd prompt (e.g., with echo %path%) it shows the previous-mentioned garbage.
And as I said, the gui (i.e. under advanced settings/environment/path) shows the path is c:python27, which is what i want. I would appreciate if either anyone who has seen this problem  OR one of the Gurus please tell me how to change the path permanently , if the usual ways are not working or how this could even happen.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I was looking at the system path in the CMD prompt and only at the USR path when I checked with the Windows-7 GUI. I thought I checked both already. Maybe this post will remind someone else to set both